# What are the purposes of としたら, とすれば, とすると?

Tags: grammar, conditionals

Taking 3 examples from my textbook:

> 車を買う**としたら**どんなタイプがいいかしら
>
> お友達が来る**とすれば**５月でしょう
>
> もしハワイに泊まる**とすると**一晩だけでしょう

What are the differences between using the above versions and using **たら**, **ば**, **なら**, and **と**? My guess is that using the forms in the example sentences are more emphatic and emphasize the "if" aspect. E.g.

> 車を買うとしたらどんなタイプがいいかしら
> = If I **WERE** to buy a car, which type would be best?

Right?

Also, I cannot use たら to ask for advice like this, can I?

> 車を買ったらどんなタイプがいいかしら

What can I use instead?

Answer (score 5):

> - 車を買うとしたらどんなタイプがいいかしら
> - 車を買うとすればどんなタイプがいいかしら
> - 車を買うとするとどんなタイプがいいかしら
>
> ---
>
> - お友達が来るとしたら５月でしょう
> - お友達が来るとすれば５月でしょう
> - お友達が来るとすると５月でしょう
>
> ---
>
> - もしハワイに泊まるとしたら一晩だけでしょう
> - もしハワイに泊まるとすれば一晩だけでしょう
> - もしハワイに泊まるとすると一晩だけでしょう

They are mostly interchangeable, but すると tends to sound like the action is likely to happen. すると should be avoided when you are talking about things that are very unlikely to happen. This is analogous to the [subjunctive mood](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/subjunctive_mood.htm) found also in English, where "past form" is often employed for something unrealistic ("If I buy a car" vs "If I bought a car").

> - もし宇宙人が地球に攻めてくるとしたら、何をするべきだろう
> - もし宇宙人が地球に攻めてくるとすれば、何をするべきだろう
> - **[?]** もし宇宙人が地球に攻めてくるとすると、何をするべきだろう

～としたら is a bit more colloquial/informal than ～とすれば, but I see no semantic difference between them for now.

車を買ったらどんなタイプがいいかしら sounds weird to me. Try 車を買うとしたら or 車を買うとすれば.